# Update MongoDB collection - JavaScript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update a value in a collection. The user clicks a button, and a number corresponding to that button, gets sent to the server to be added to the collection.

I cannot get the collection to update, but it works fine in the console if i use `db.orders.update()`

orders model:

```
// DB Initiation stuff

var orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    status: String,
    rated: Number
});

var collection = 'orders';
var Order = db.model('Order', orderSchema, collection);

module.exports = Order;
```

client side (when button click)

```
// starID = 5; id = 50e6a57808a1d92dcd000001
socket.emit('rated', {rated: starID, id: id});
```

socket.js:

```
var Order = require('../models/orders');

socket.on('rated', function(data) { 
  /* Probably a better way to do this but, wrap
   * the id in 'ObjectId(id)'
   */
  var id = 'ObjectId("'+data.id+'")';
  Order.update( {_id: id}, {$set: {rated: data.rated}} );
   socket.emit('updated', {
     note: 'Some HTML notification to append'
   });  
});
```

Comment: Try using `var id=ObjectId.fromString(data.id);` instead of creating a string (where `ObjectId` = `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything stated and it just didn't seem to work, so I changed the update code to:

```
Order.findOne({_id : id}, function(err, doc) {
  doc.rated = data.rated;
  doc.status = data.status;
  doc.save();
});
```

And now it works fine. Thank you to everyone who contributed to answering

Answer (score 1):

Let Mongoose do the casting of the `id` string to an `ObjectId`:

```
socket.on('rated', function(data) { 
  Order.update( {_id: data.id}, {$set: {rated: data.rated}} );
   socket.emit('updated', {
     note: 'Some HTML notification to append'
   });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose expects a String as id. So passing an ObjectId does not work.
Try:

```
Order.update( {_id: id.toString()}, ....... );
```

It is safe to use toString with both String and ObjectId.